# JSON to Scala code generation

Tags: json, scala, scala-2.10, scalac

I have a JSON which is an output of another application, I want to make dynamic Scala  code (*.scala file ) from this JSON (can not pre define class/bean as the JSON structure depends many other parameters). Is there any API available for this ?

Comment: if the class is not defined at the compile time, how do you plan on using it in your other (non-generated) code? Can you show and example, how you would use such tool?

Comment: There are ways to load this newly generated class using classloader and instantiate. I tried to manage create case classes by reading JSON, but wondering if any API already does this . You could also check this http://json2caseclass.cleverapps.io/

Comment: I understand, how you can load them and instantiate. But how are you going to be _using_ those instances? The link you gave is _static_ generation - you give it sample json, it generates case classes, and you then compile them with your static code. That's not what you are talking about at all if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: I do not use that link , I gave you to understand case class generation . I will treat the generated class (from JSON) as string then load using class loader . Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I understand the class generation, thank you very much. I don't understand what _you_ are trying to do with it, because what you are asking doesn't seem to make any sense. You load it using the classloader ... _then what_? 
`val loadedInstance: AnyRef = generateAndLoad(json)` ... Now what? How will you be using this variable?

Comment: I have working example , I will share when time permits. The idea is create dynamic class from JSON ( do not worry about class name - I have class template ) and the generated class loaded and instantiated ( this is like bean now ).

Comment: You keep talking about "loading and instantiating" it. _This is not at all what I am asking_. I understand how you can load and instantiate it. What I don't understand is _why_ you want to load and instantiate it. Without having any type information about this generated class _at compile time_, pretty much, the only way you can access it's data is using reflection anyway. So, what's the benefit of having it generated in the first place, over just using a `Map[String, Any]` to begin with, which is not only simpler, but also _ways_ more efficient than reflection?

Comment: There's this UI tool that can convert complex JSON schemas to case classes: https://cchandurkar.github.io/case-class-generator/

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like below:

http://json2caseclass.cleverapps.io/

https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/36m951/json2caseclass_a_tool_to_generate_scala_case/

Comment: Looks like a web application.. I want an API which is compatible with my existing Scala code.

Comment: http://json2caseclass.cleverapps.io/ is not answering this specific question, but it's a nice tool!

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this one: https://github.com/julianpeeters/case-class-generator

Allows runtime data to serve as Scala case class definitions:

Case classes defined and loaded at runtime
Pseudo Type-Provider via type alias

And also this one: 
Maybe this one is better, you need to generate some code first, and then call it.

http://yefremov.net/blog/scala-code-generation/